# Docker container, how to use unit test in CI and don't add these dependencies into production?

Tags: php, docker, continuous-integration, composer-php

I have a question about using PHPUnit and other QA tools with Docker.

By default, `phpunit/phpunit` is listed under `require-dev` in `composer.json`. Therefore, you need these dev dependencies for both development and CI.

Online sources recommend **building only one image** for development, staging, and production. During `composer install`, PHPUnit and other dev dependencies will be installed in all environments (development, staging, and production). However, it is not advisable to have development dependencies on staging and production (`composer install --no-dev)`.

However, if `composer install --no-dev` is used on CI, these dependencies will not be installed, and unit tests cannot be run.

To address this issue, a possible workaround is to move `phpunit/phpunit` from `require-dev` to `require` in the `composer.json` file. However, I believe it is not advisable as both Laravel and CakePHP frameworks place `phpunit/phpunit` under `require-dev`.

An alternative solution would be to follow these steps:

1. Install all dependencies (`composer install`)
2. Perform QA and unit testing
3. Remove dependencies and reinstall only production dependencies (e.g. `rm -r vendor && composer install --no-dev`).

However, this may result in changes to the code. We cannot guarantee that our application will continue to function with this workaround.

How should you deal with this situation?

Here is my Dockerfile used for CI, staging & production.

```
FROM harbor.dev/php:8.2-fpm
USER www-data

# First install dependencies, could be cached
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data PHP/composer.json PHP/composer.lock /var/www/html/
RUN composer install --no-interaction && composer dumpautoload -o

# Then copy files
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data PHP /var/www/html/
```

Comment: I run unit tests in a non-Docker environment, before I build an image or do anything with Docker at all.

Comment: Why not build **two** images? How do these dependencies go into your development image otherwise?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, but you have to take care manually that you have exactly the same environment between Docker and the non-Docker. Risk of issue is pretty high with this solution, especially in our team with 4 developers.

Comment: @NicoHaase Because it takes a lot of times to create a Docker image on Teamcity (CI Process). Time to execute the build process in the CI could be too long. Finally, I found out a workaround. I install only production stuff into Docker image. On Teamcity, you can execute unit tests with Docker container env, but code on Ubuntu. So dev dependencies are installed on Ubuntu (in Teamcity working dir). I think it's docker exec cmd with some parameters. That's how I handle the situation. Good point is that we keep the same Docker image for the whole process.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, of course we have another Docker image with dev dependencies for development on our local laptop. Then, after building the image with the CI tool, we keep the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim, without citation, that nebulous *"online sources"* recommend building only one image for all environments. Notwithstanding the legitimacy of this claim, one might suppose the meaning of such a recommendation would be to just have a *common base*, rather than sharing the same image verbatim in all environments, since this is seldom possible, let alone wise.

To create a common base image, install only production dependencies in your image.

```bash
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

N.B. `composer install` also creates the autoloader, so the additional `composer dumpautoload` step in your example is redundant, particularly since we specified the `--optimize-autoloader` flag as well.

Now we have a production-ready base image, we can push it to a repository somewhere (or just work with it locally) by specifying it as the source for our development image.

```bash
docker build --tag app:prod --file prod.Dockerfile .
```

```
# dev.Dockerfile
FROM app:prod

# Composer will install dev dependencies by default.
RUN composer install
```

```bash
docker build --tag app:dev --file dev.Dockerfile .
```

That is, if you really need or want a dev image at all. It is supposed you could just run `composer install` on your production image in CI without a Dockerfile by just instructing the Docker daemon directly, e.g. `docker exec MyContainer composer install`.

Comment: Thank for the tips. Well, I read a couple of articles online. That why I don't share a specific articles. It's kind of summary.

Comment: Thank for the composer install tips. Regarding docker exec, you're right. I'm using Teamcity and Docker build step is using "docker exec My Container" cmd. It execute code on Ubuntu server (in teamcity repo) with Docker container. I was thinking about such a solution as well. Thanks for your great answer.